# How to limit Pandas loc selection

Tags: python, pandas

I search Pandas DataFrame by *loc* -for example like this

```
x = df.loc[df.index.isin(['one','two'])]
```

But I need only the first row of the result. If I use

```
x = df.loc[df.index.isin(['one','two'])].iloc[0]
```

I get error in the case that no row is found. Of course, I can select all the rows (the first example) and then check if result is empty or not. But I seek some more efficient way (the dataframe can be long). Is there any?

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.isin(['one','two'])].head(1)` ??

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks, thats solution I like

Answer (score 2):

#### `pandas.Index.duplicated`

The `pandas.Index` object has a `duplicated` method that identifies all repeated values after the first occurance.

```
x[~x.index.duplicated()]
```

If you wanted to ...

```
df[df.index.isin(['one', 'two']) & ~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Comment: ohh, didnt understand the question till i read your answer. :) +1

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be good. Do you know, how the inner procedure of the Pandas works? Because if the complete (=duplicated) selection is created in the first step and then repeated occurences are omitted in the second step, then  the performance would be suboptimal (unnecessary rows are created in the first step an deleted in the second step). Optimal would be something like *LIMIT* clause in SQL.